# Classifying zones in an x, y axis

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing frame-by-frame x and y points of animals tracked from a video.

It looks like this:

```
date       frame position     x     y
   <date>     <dbl> <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2019-08-26     1 1        138.   67  
 2 2019-08-26     1 2        166    89.5
 3 2019-08-26     1 3        147   127  
 4 2019-08-26     1 4        113   130. 
 5 2019-08-26     1 5         91    98  
 6 2019-08-26     2 1        138.   67  
 7 2019-08-26     2 2        166    89.5
 8 2019-08-26     2 3        147   127  
 9 2019-08-26     2 4        112.  130. 
10 2019-08-26     2 5         90.5  98  
11 2019-08-26     3 1        138.   67  
12 2019-08-26     3 2        166    89.5
13 2019-08-26     3 3        146.  127  
14 2019-08-26     3 4        112   130. 
15 2019-08-26     3 5         91.2  98.2
16 2019-08-26     4 1        138.   67  
17 2019-08-26     4 2        166    89.5
18 2019-08-26     4 3        147.  128. 
19 2019-08-26     4 4        111.  129. 
20 2019-08-26     4 5         91.2  97.2
```

From this, my goal is to classify the points into discrete observations by creating a new column called "activity". The idea is to classify the points if they are within an imaginary polygon/area and must be within both the x and y argument and not only either one.

For example, I want any points within 100 and 110 in y and 110 and 140 in x "zone" to be classified as "interaction". Points outside the "zone" will be classified as something else.

I have tried this:

```
full_data %>% 
  mutate(activity = ifelse(y %in% c(100:110) & x %in% c(110:140), "interaction",  
                           ifelse(y <= 30 & y >= 160 | x <= 60 & x >= 190, "outside", "none" )))
```

However, this does not seem to create the desired result as seen in this image:

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qqHc.png)

I initially thought that a nested ifelse statement with multiple arguments will be ok. Any suggestions on how to go about this problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT 1:
Added a subset of the full dataset. This looks long for a minimally reproducible example but it replicates the problem I have been having.

```
full_data_sub = structure(list(date = structure(c(18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 
                                                  18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134, 18134), class = "Date"), 
                               frame = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
                                         15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
                                         30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
                                         45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
                                         60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
                                         75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 
                                         90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 
                                         104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 
                                         116, 117, 118, 119, 120), position = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
                               x = c(113, 112.5, 112, 111.4, 112.1, 112.1, 112.1, 112.1, 
                                     112.6, 112.75, 112.6, 113.1, 113.5, 112.25, 113, 112.9, 113, 
                                     113, 113, 113.1, 113, 113, 113, 112.5, 113.3, 112.4, 111.9, 
                                     112.2, 112.2, 112.8, 112.4, 113.2, 112.9, 113.5, 115, 115.1, 
                                     116.1, 116.6, 116.6, 117.6, 117.75, 117.9, 118.9, 120.1, 
                                     121.1, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123.5, 123.5, 123.1, 123.6, 123.6, 
                                     123.1, 121.6, 121.6, 121.1, 120.25, 119.75, 119.75, 119.6, 
                                     117.6, 116.6, 114.6, 114, 113.9, 113, 113, 113, 113.5, 112.5, 
                                     112, 111, 111, 111, 110.9, 109.4, 109.5, 109.5, 110, 109.9, 
                                     109.4, 111, 111, 112.5, 112, 113.5, 114.5, 115.5, 116, 115.5, 
                                     114, 113, 110, 110.5, 110.5, 111, 112, 115, 115.5, 117.5, 
                                     117.5, 118, 116.5, 115, 114.5, 115.5, 117, 118.5, 118, 118, 
                                     118, 117.5, 117.5, 117, 113.5, 110.5, 108, 107), y = c(129.5, 
                                                                                            129.5, 129.5, 128.55, 129.2, 129.7, 129.7, 129.7, 129.7, 
                                                                                            129.35, 129.2, 129.2, 129.5, 129.35, 129.5, 129.85, 129.5, 
                                                                                            129.5, 129.5, 129.7, 129.5, 130, 129.5, 129.5, 129.15, 128.85, 
                                                                                            128.35, 127.5, 126.5, 124.65, 123.85, 122.5, 120.35, 119.5, 
                                                                                            118, 117.7, 116.7, 116.2, 116.7, 117.2, 117.35, 117.55, 118.05, 
                                                                                            119.2, 119.7, 118.5, 117.5, 117, 116.5, 116.5, 116, 116.2, 
                                                                                            115.7, 115.2, 115.2, 114.2, 113.7, 113.7, 112.85, 111.85, 
                                                                                            111.35, 111.7, 112.2, 114.2, 113.7, 113.5, 114.35, 113.5, 
                                                                                            111.5, 110, 110, 110, 109.5, 109.5, 109, 107.5, 107.35, 105.85, 
                                                                                            105.5, 104, 102, 100.85, 99.85, 100, 100.5, 100, 99.5, 98.5, 
                                                                                            97, 97.5, 97.5, 98.5, 97.5, 95.5, 94.5, 94.5, 93, 90.5, 90, 
                                                                                            90.5, 91, 91, 91, 91.5, 89, 86.5, 85.5, 83, 81, 77.5, 75.5, 
                                                                                            75, 75, 74.5, 75, 75.5, 76, 75, 73, 71.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                      -120L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
full_data_sub <- full_data_sub %>% 
  mutate(activity = "none") %>%
  mutate(activity = ifelse((y >= 100 & y <= 110) & (x >= 110 & x <= 140), "interaction", activity)) %>%
  mutate(activity = ifelse(y < 30 | y > 160 | x < 60 | x > 190, "outside", activity))
```

Comment: I have provided a subset from the original dataset, please see the edited version.

Comment: this works great! Thank you for the help!